# Opening GRASS GIS 7.8.4 Results in Error

Tags: grass-gis, c++, windows, assertionerror, grass-7.8

When trying to create a new location in GRASS GIS 7.8.4 on a machine running Windows 11 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 540, in OnWizard
    gWizard = LocationWizard(parent=self,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\location_wizard\wizard.py", line 2318, in __init__
    wizbmp = wx.Image(imagePath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(0, 0), "C") == 0" failed at D:\src\osgeo4w\src\wxwidgets\wxwidgets-3.1.5-0df1d81acd6f1be8624022f8eecb51679008ca40\src\common\intl.cpp(1694) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
```

Not sure how to resolve this and haven't found a comprehensive solution so far. I've also trying doing a standalone installation of GRASS GIS 8.0 and still encounter the same.

Comment: For reference: this has been reported here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/2101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a very simple fix. Just needed to go to Control Panel and change my Region format to match my system locale

[image: System Locale]

[image: Region Format]